# How do I disable a jQuery function after some other event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to disable the hover event on a particular list when another event occurs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`unbind`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unbind) function to remove those events.

```
$('#theListId').unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
```

Comment: can you confirm this works on hover? it works on unbinding click, but not working on the hover function.

Comment: I've updated my answer to the correct syntax. I got the previous code from http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover#examples, but apparently you can't actually combine unbind statements like that.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use:

```
$('#item').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

Which is same as:

```
$('#theListId').unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function test(){ alert('test'); };

$( "li" ).hover( test );

$("li").unbind('hover', test);
```

Comment: hover is not a real JavaScript event, and can't be unbound like that.